# Most suitable way to transport entities from service to front end in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have currently found out three possible ways to send objects (entities) from service to the front end.

1. **JSON views**
2. **DTO using MapStruct** for example.
3. **DTO without MapStruct** (as per first comment)

I guess that using JSON view may cause issues with lazy loading inside the entities since any entities having this will be outside of the hibernate session (assuming that we are working with `@Transactional` in our services which is most common).

I also don't prefer the third option because in that case, I need also to implement the mappers myself.

I finally chose to work with MapStruct. Is that the best way?

Comment: 3. DTO without Mapstruct, in order to have plain simple, readable, refactorable code that won't break as soon as you change a property name in an entity and forget to change it in the DTO.

Comment: In that case I need also to implement my self the mappers (to map from entity to dto)

Comment: And that's super-simple code to write.

Comment: What persistence layer do you use?

Comment: @JB Nizen, have you seen the code that MapStruct generates? The code looks like written by hand, can you please point us to a code generated by MapStruct that isn't simple and easy to read? For the rename, you know that you can configure your mappers to create a compile error when not all properties are mapped into the target?

Comment: @Filip I guess you can do pretty much whatever you want. But this comes at a cost: you add complexity to the build, one more thing to learn, property names as strings in annotations and thus not refactorable automatically, a loss of flexibility because it's all generated code, and all that for a gain that is minimal, because writing the code by hand is simple enough. That's my opinion anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet IDEs like IntelliJ with the plugin for Mapstruct can change those mapping strings automatically during refactoring and renaming.

Comment: @dersvenhesse good hint. I used to run MapStruct as a gradle task each time I needed to generate the mappers. It's better than to add it to my Intellij

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a most suitable way to transport entities from service to front end. It should be a decision done by the development team and what works best for them. However, me personally I would like to have the entities decoupled from the REST DTOs, which automatically rules out the first option of using JSON Views.

The other 2 options DTO using MapStruct and DTO without MapStruct (manual code) are the same. The generated code by MapStruct is a simple easy to read code, exactly as a human would write it. You can customize the generation and you can add custom mappings (MapStruct would then back off).